# How can I store extra data with a validation error message in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm trying to store some additional data along with the standard error message in a custom validator in Rails 3.

For example, (ignoring built-in validators) suppose I wanted to check to see if a post is a duplicate before it's saved. I might write my custom validation method like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  # prevent duplicate posts
  validate do |post|
    duplicates = Post.find_all_by_body(body)
    errors.add_to_base("Post is a duplicate!") if duplicates.length

    # something like this is desired:
    # errors.add_to_base("Post is a duplicate",
    #  :extra => { :duplicates => duplicates })
  end

end
```

This will let the user know there are duplicates, but along with adding the error message I would also like to store the duplicates so they can be displayed to the user. How would I store the list of duplicate posts retrieved during validation such that it is associated with the record's errors for the `body` field, and available to my view?

A simpler example might be length validation: If a field exceeds its maximum length, how can I store the maximum length along with an error message without simply interpolating it into the message as Rails currently does?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for a solution to the duplicates problem or a more generic how to store more data with your errors?

Comment: @Aditya See update. I'm after a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not had to do this before, but my first thought is to create a new method on the object called duplicates.

```
attr_accessor :duplicates
```

Then in your custom validate method, you can set the duplicates on the object making them available to the view when you render the errors. Notice your current code doesn't change much:

```
validate do |post|
  duplicates = Post.find_all_by_body(body)
  errors.add_to_base("Post is a duplicate!") if duplicates.size > 0
end
```

You would then have to intercept that error in the view manually so that you can print out all the duplicates if the "Post is a duplicate!" error is encountered.

Comment: Spot on, was just in the process of posting something near-identical.

Comment: You may want to make it self.duplicates otherwise it will resolve to be a local variable and wont get plonked in your attr_accessor.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass options to the error but they are only used as substitution in i18n templates. To make a long story short, no you can't store meta-data about your error in the errors hash. If you need such a functionality you'll need to look into the ActiveModel::Errors module in Rails core.

Update:
Another solution could be that instead of pushing a string into error hash, you stuff an instance of your own class, a class which quacks like a string but would be decorated with extra methods and state and such like.